# Writing two matrices to a .dat file using C

Tags: c

I'm writing a code that will some matrices and put them in a .dat file using C.

I'm writing in NetBeans as an IDE.  Netbeans says the code is good for build but when it runs it fails and doesn't even tell me why.

Could there possibly be something wrong with the IDE I am using?

Here is the section of code (yes I have stdio.h and stdlib.h included in the source file).

```
   //this is supposed to make a pair of example matrices.
   double A[10][10];
   double B[10][10];

   int i , j;

   for (i=0; i < 10 ; i++)
   {
       for(i=0; i < 10 ; i++)
       {
           A[i][j]= 1.0 ;
           B[i][j]= 1.0 ;
       }
   }

   //this is supposed to make the .dat file
   FILE *fp2;


   fp2 = fopen("MatricesFile.dat","w");

   if(fp2 == NULL)
   {
       printf("Error in opening file");
       return 1;
   }

   else
   {
      for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
      {
         for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++)
         {
            fwrite(&A[i][j], sizeof(A[i][j]), 1, fp2);  
            fwrite(&B[i][j], sizeof(B[i][j]), 1, fp2);
         }    
      }
   }

   fclose(fp2);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `for (i=0; i < 10 ; i++) { for (i=0; i < 10 ; i++) { ... } }` I guess it should be `j` wihtin the second loop.

Comment: You probably should open the file to write in binary mode: fopen(...,"wb");

Comment: It's not the IDEs job to tell you about your runtime bugs.

Comment: But it *is* the compiler's job to tell you that `j` is an uninitialised variable.

Comment: You should turn on compiler warnings(such as `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` in GCC).

Comment: @Weather Vane - It's not, actually.   In practice, compilers often do (or can be configured to do) that.   But the standard requires nothing of the sort - it simply says that accessing the value of an uninitialised variable gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: First it doesn't compile. Then it compiles, but doesn't link. Then it compiles, links, but crashes. Then it compiles, links, runs, but doesn't do what I want. *Only then* does it compile, link, run, and behave correctly. You are somewhere in step 3 or 4; you didn't specify. As an aside: It is exceedingly rare that one of the tools is at fault in any of the steps.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Actually, the OP -- like anybody -- should turn on `-Wall`, and probably `-Wextra` unless s/he has a good reason not to.

Comment: @Peter, though *the standard* does not require compilers to emit warnings about uninitialized variables, that in no way prevents *users* from attributing that responsibility to them.  And we generally do.  At minimum, that's a quality of implementation issue.  A compiler that does not emit such warnings -- whether by default or only when asked to do -- does not fulfill my expectations.  It does not do part of the job I expect of my compiler.

Comment: `but when it runs it fails` Could you be more specific about that part? Is the output wrong? Is the program crashing? Is the program running forever?

Comment: No worries.  Added some new stuff.  Good news is the program no longer fails.  Bad news is it gets caught in a loop, porbably due to something else going wrong in another section.  Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two obvious problems in the code.

When nesting loops, control inner loops and outer loops using different variables.   At least one of your loops uses `i` to control both inner and outer loop.

When using `fwrite()` and `fread()`, open the file in binary mode  (e.g. to open for writing, use mode `"wb"`).   Otherwise data written out is not necessarily recovered correctly when reading.

And get out of the habit of blaming your IDE or compiler whenever you encounter a problem.  IDEs and compilers have bugs, sure, but the vast majority of problems you encounter will be due to flaws in your coding.   As is the case here.

Comment: Oh! Thanks.  Code is working better I think.  Its not failing, but now is stuck in some kind of loop, probably due to something else going on in another section.  Appreciated!